# Import {multiple} materil-ui still error in react js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, npm

I have material UI installed, but still can't import it. no error in my code, but when I run my react project I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgYZb.png) error.

```js
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Button, Container, Grid, TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { firebaseAuthentication, githubProvider } from '../config/firebase';
```

This is version information from my package.json

```js
{
  "name": "auth-github",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^5.0.0-beta.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
```

Comment: Did you generate this application using create-react-app or is this done using a custom webpack configuration? As @Roopa Rauniyar mentioned in their answer, this is most likely not related to material-ui. If it's a custom webpack configuration, you may need to include a plugin to handle .css imports, such as [css-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/).

Comment: this is a custom webpack config, I've tried to add .css, but the result is the same.

Comment: Are you attempting to import a file called Apps.css anywhere in your project?

Comment: Yeah, I do, there is in the same folder.